# JavaScript browser check and hide div content

Tags: javascript

Checking if the Browser is chrome or not, If not chrome then hide the div. But the div show from all browser, but browser checking is working correct.
Here is the code:

```
var isChrome = window.chrome;
var showHide = document.getElementById("show");
if(isChrome) {
   alert("Okay");
   showHide.style.display='block';
} else { 
   alert("Not from Google Chrome Browser");
   showHide.style.display='none';
}
```

and the div looks like:

```
<div id="show">Hello!</div>
```

The Div always showing from all browser.
But it is checking the browser correctly. But the div is not hidden.

It is a experimental and educational script I am coding, and I am not in pro yet. :)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The Div is not hidden form all browser.

Comment: Do you execute the code before `#show` exists? Place the snippet to `window.onload` handler function, or just before ending `body` tag, then it should work.

Comment: Yes @Teemu the code working with browser checking.

Comment: @SubhajitSarkar I've understood that from your comments to other answers, please re-read my comment above.

Comment: @Teemu It works thanks a lot. Can you explain what happen when it is not in body onload.

Comment: The `head` section is always loaded and parsed before `body`. If you try to refer an element within `body` in the `head` during parsing, the element doesn't exist, since even the `body` doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Teemu. You cleared the concept clearly. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
```

or

```
var chrome = window.chrome;
```

Answer (score 0):

actually window.chrome returns an object and generally you convert it to Boolean to check in if

```
isChrome = Boolean(window.chrome)
```

(in this case your isChrome variable would either contain an object or would be undefined/null, even that would work for browser detection.)

also, regarding your div, have you tried setting any other property to check if the div has loaded, when this javascript is running.

you can `alert(showHide.id)` to check.

if this is the case. try moving your code to `onLoad` or towards the `end of body tag`

Comment: Why? `isChrome` would be `undefined`, if `window.chrome` doesn't exist. `undefined` is evaluated being falsy in `if`'s condition. If it exists, it's evaluated truthy.

Comment: yes, you are correct, his code would detect the browser correctly, i was trying to convey what is generally considered the correct way to use window.chrome. i ll edit the language